# Flutter How to vertical scroll a screen like a book

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

[e-book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb9Gj.jpg)

I want to make an e-book with scrolling screens that are images with Flutter

Comment: You need to post the tried code.

Comment: I am asking for code how should I try something I don't know ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PageView. Using page view you can either scroll page horizontally or vertically.

```
PageView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    return _buildPage();
  },
  itemCount: listItemCount, 
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
)
```